# Download a .zip larger than 20 GB from OneDrive

Tags: bash, curl, wget, onedrive

I am trying to download a 157gb `.zip` file from OneDrive (I have tried both `curl` and `wget`) to a machine on which I am `ssh` connected. I usually run `screen`, launch the download and then detach and disconnect.  I have noticed that each time the download ends without error with an output of exactly 20GB, and this seems to be a limitation of OneDrive.
In fact, as you can read in this discussion:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/onedrive-web-version-cannot-download-files-larger/2d88fc5f-beb9-49e2-9411-d30636e6e88b

Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: If the protocol is HTTP(S), it allows you to download a slice at a particular offset. If the other end is operated by Microsoft, all bets are off, though.

Answer (score 0):

As first thing check if `wget` do indeed see file of size 157GB under given URL, by doing

```
wget --spider URLTOFILE
```

you would get basic information about file withoud download it, filesize will be described as `Length:`, then check if it does support [Partial gimmick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) as follows

```
wget --server-response --spider URLTOFILE
```

and then check if output contain `Accept-Ranges: bytes`, if yes then it might be possible to exploit Partial gimmick to get whole file, start following command

```
wget -c -O file.zip URLTOFILE
```

and then after it do get first 20GB then run it again and observe if it does download further part of your file.